# how can I use javascript array in google table chart?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, charts, google-visualization

I have a javascript array, how can I input row for google table chart? (google chart visualization)

I tried to insert as array it self, but it does not work.

```
en <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myarr = new Array();
        myarr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"));


        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);


        data.addColumn('string', 'Zipcode');
        data.addColumn('string', 'City');
        data.addColumn('String', 'State');

        //arr[0][0] to arr[0][arr[0].length] is column name 

        data.addRows([

            //I don't know how to work here with array



        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', 
height: '100%'});*/

</script>
```

array is two-d array.
example 
[example array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uspWQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all your data is in the array, then you can use method --> `arrayToDataTable`

```
    var myarr = new Array();
    myarr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"));

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(myarr);
```